# Union of Set Differences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to think of a counterexample to the equality

A \ (B ∩ C) = (A \ B) ∪ (A \ C)

I keep drawing various combinations of 3 circles intersecting (or not intersecting) to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice by using the following laws of Algebra of sets:

$$ A \setminus B = A \cap B^c $$

$$ A \cap ( B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$$

$$ (A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c $$

We have that

$$ A \setminus (B \cap C ) =  A \cap (B \cap C)^c = A \cap ( B^c \cup C^c) = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap C^c) = (A \setminus B) \cup ( A \setminus C) $$

Answer (score 3):

Because it's true.

$A \setminus (B \cap C) =A \cap (B \cap C)^C= A \cap (B^C \cup C^C)= (A \setminus B) ∪ (A \setminus C)$